# Understanding epsilon positive.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, epsilon-delta

I have a very basic question about $\epsilon$ which confuses me. Suppose we have somewhere $f \geq \epsilon ~ \forall ~ \epsilon >0$. Can we conclude that $f(x)>0$ or we can just say $f(x) \geq 0$. Similarly let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary, can we still say $\frac{1}{\epsilon}< \infty ~ \forall ~ \epsilon>0$ ?. If there are any references where the similar situation arises. It will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Even if $f \geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$ you can conclude that $f(x) >0$. Cretainly $f \geq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ implies that $f(x) >0$. It is true that $\frac 1 {\epsilon} <\infty$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: It's more correct to write quantifier first, then sentence: $(\forall \varepsilon > 0) (f \geqslant \varepsilon)$ gives, that $f$ cannot be usual real number. For such case is used extended real line.